# How to perform a quick check if the file directory for a script in matlab is correct?

Tags: list, matlab, indexing

I have a script which relies on different files located in specific folders which are important to run the script without errors. In order to define the path location I decided to create many variables with the according path location name as string:

```
file directory var   file directory location            % default entries which
                                                        % only work with my computer
fd_1  =            '\C:\Testrun\pathfinder.xls\';            
fd_2  =            '\C:\Testrun\pathfilter.slx\';
fd_3  =            '\C:\Testrun\splinegenerator.xls\';
fd_4  =            '\C:\Testrun\loftcreator.xls\';
fd_5  =            '\C:\Testrun\surface_to_volume.xls\';
fd_6  =            '\C:\Testrun\stp_creator.xls\';
fd_7  =            '\C:\Testrun\CAD_file.stp\';
fd_8  =            '\C:\Testrun\CAD_support_1.atm\';
fd_9  =            '\C:\Testrun\CAD_support_2.atm\';
fd_10 =            '\C:\Testrun\CAD_support_3.atm\';
```

This allowed me to use my script on my computer. However this was a pretty static solution which only works for one pc. Hence I need the following dynmamic routine to be coded:

```
0.) I created a while loop in order to rerun my script with the switch case/expression:

<<<here is the missing code for the file directory check>>>  
%(I wanted to use the "strcmp" command to compare the strings with each other?)

<<<Here is my code with the specific while loop to rerun it>>>


1.) Before I enter this loop need to perform a quick check, if the files are correctly located.
2.) If the file directory cannot be assigned to the specific variables responsible for the file 
    directory name (e.g directory could not be found), a new file directory will be choosen by the 
    user
3.) The newly choosen file directory will be stored with the default file directory in a list
4.) The variable responsible for the file directory changes according to the list index which the 
    user choose from the list of stored file directory names
5.) The selection of the specific list index as well as the changes in the list will be permenantly 
    stored (The changes in the list should be saved and recalled again in the script upon rerunning 
    or exiting/reopening the script)
6.) The list index can be deleted if the user is unsatisfied with the file directory (e.g due the 
    file directory corruption)
```

Is it possible to write such a code and how would it be structered?

Comment: What is the question here? there are various questions within this post and some of them are more or less answerable, but the last one, "is it possible", the answer is "yes, but we won't write such code for you because 1) we dont write your code 2)your problem statement is vague".   

Can you try to narrow down what exactly you are having probolems with?

Comment: Yes. I will explain again. As I mentioned above I have a specific set of variables which contain information above the current location of a file in a folder. My issue is that I do not want to manually edit each of those variables if I want to run the script on a different computer. Therefore I would need a storage systems which adds new file directories, saves new entries or deletes older ones.

Comment: Hence I am struggling to apply write such a code because I am not familiar with the code achitecture since I have not encountered such a problem before

Comment: Its still not very clear to me. Do you want code that creates those files? or folders? if you run in a different computer, the files don't exist, so how are you going to create them? How can we help to create them, if we have no idea what the files have inside?

Comment: I guess my question is: I seem to understand that what you want is to fill those path-names in the variables when you run this code on a different computer. But if you run it in a different computer, and the files are in a different path, how would you know? You cant test all existing paths of the computer (it would take too long), so how do you know where the files are? If you can answer that maybe then we can find a way to let the code know :)

Comment: The files are already created. I want a code which checks, if the file name is currently located in their respective folder. I think this can be done by comparing the strings of the file name and the file directory. But I am unable to convert this idea in a code.

Comment: So you want `isfile(fd_1)` ? That will check if the path in `fd_1` is an actual file in the computer or not. (there is also `isfolder` and some other variations)

Comment: I never heard of this code before but you are implying that this is a method to scan the existence of a file on a different computer, right?

Comment: I am not implying it, I googled "MATLAB check if file exists" and it points out to the very well written documentation, where it explains what it does and how. I know you seem new  at programming, but the best programming skill is using google :) Always google, MATLAB documentation is one of the best in the world . https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfile.html

Comment: Of course, you can not "just check" if a file exist on a different computer, unless you have access to it remotely, but if you do, then it has a path that you can check with `isfile`.

Comment: I have used your link to check the documentations and it seems that I get logical results as an output. (0 if the file does not exist and 1 if the directory is present). I will try code it now

Comment: Always try to check the matlab documentation first, its really super useful and it will save you time :)

Comment: (1) Is there an installation script that puts all those files in all those directories? Have that script update your M-file with the right paths, and require that the user don’t mess with the files after. (2) Why is your program spread out over so many directories? You need to keep your code together, in a single directory. Give each function a unique name, and add the directory to the MATLAB path. Now you don’t need to worry about directories at all, just call the function.

Comment: Well I have all my files in one main folder (.m matlabfile, functions and other files). The idea was to check beforehand if the file directory exists on different computers by using the "isfile" "isfolder" command in order get logical values. These values should be used in a if statement in order to (a) [create a new folder, search existing files, copy the files in the newly created folder and save that decision permanently] or (b)[run the script if the file directory exists] Therofore I am asking for commands which allow these kind of file directory and file/folder manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to put  all those folders and files in the same path of main program, by this way, no need to mention drive letter like c:\ or d:, just mentiob folder name and its subfolders, and you can copy the main folder and run your program in another computer without changing anything, just run the main program.

Comment: To add to this, you can always use relative paths, e.g. `fd_1=../pathfinder.xls` etc

Comment: I already left all the files in the mainfolder "Testrun" with ma .m matlab file. I will try to check them all together at one.